# Object #<Promise> has no method 'limit'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

when I run code

```
  var collection = db.get('categories');
 console.log(collection.find().limit(1).sort( { _id : -1 } ));
```

on nodejs using mongodb I am getting error  Object # has no method 'limit' . I am a beginner to node and really stuck on this section of node

here is full code for geting last insert document.

```
router.post('/addcategory', function(req, res) {

// Set our internal DB variable
var db = req.db;

// Get our form values. These rely on the "name" attributes
var name = req.body.name;
var description = req.body.description;




// Set our collection
var collection = db.get('categories');

// Submit to the DB
collection.insert({

    "name" : name,
    "description" : description,


}, function (err, doc) {
    if (err) {
        // If it failed, return error
        res.send("There was a problem adding the information to the database.");
    }
    else {
        // And forward to success page
        /******************/
        console.log(collection.find().limit(1).sort( { _id : -1 } ));


        /*************/
    }
});
});
```

Comment: What version of the mongodb driver are you using? Does it help if you change  `var collection = db.get('categories');` to `var collection = db.collection('categories');`?

Comment: What module(s) are you using for mongodb?

Comment: @JoGoFo when I do that I am getting this error `Object #<Manager> has no method 'collection' `

Comment: @mscdex   I am using mongo and monk and I am not sure it is correct `var mongo = require('mongodb');
var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk('localhost:27017/glass') `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key piece of missing information here was that you are using Monk, not the native MongoDB Node.JS driver. The command you have for `find()` is how you would use the native driver (with the changes suggested by @BlakesSeven above for asynchronity), but Monk works a little bit differently.

Try this instead:

```
collection.find({}, { limit : 1, sort : { _id : -1 } },  function (err,res) { 
    console.log(res);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The method is still asynchronous so you still need to invoke itm either as a promise with `.then()` or a callback. No methods are sychronous and return results in-line.

Also the result returned from the driver is s "Cursor" and not the object(s) you expect. You either iterate the returned cursor or just use `.toArray()` or similar to convert:

```js
collection.find().limit(1).sort({ "_id": -1 }).toArray().then(function(docs) {
    console.log(docs[0]);
});
```

Or:

```js
collection.find().limit(1).sort({ "_id": -1 }).toArray(function(err,docs) {
    console.log(docs[0]);
});
```

But really the whole premise is not correct. You seem to basically want to return what you just inserted. Event with the correction in your code, the returned document is not necessarily the one you just inserted, but rather the last one inserted into the collection, which could have occurred from another operation or call to this route from another source.

If you want what you inserted back then rather call the [`.insertOne()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#insertOne) method and inspect the result:

```js
collection.insertOne({ "name": name, "description": description },function(err,result) {
  if (err) {
    res.send("There was an error");
  } else {
    console.log(result.ops)
  }
});
```

The `.insert()` method is considered deprecated, but basically returns the same thing. The consideration is that they return a [`insertWriteOpResult`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#~insertWriteOpResult) object where the `ops` property contains the document(s) inserted and their `_id` value(s),

Comment: I am getting this error  `TypeError: Object #<Promise> has no method 'limit'` when I put your code . I dont know where I am wrong.

Comment: @Mohammed Yes that is your question and it is what this answers. The object you are trying to return in your code is not the "result" but a "Promise Object", hence the error. What this shows you is how to get the result from that object by changing your code. It also addresses that you seem likely to want the returned object to be the one you just inserted. It will not likely be so by your code, and an alternate way to ensure this is listed.